# Which process reads Xft font settings?

Tags: font-rendering

I use the Blackbox window manager and in my `~/.Xresources` file I have a number of settings, like `Xft.antialias` and `Xft.hinting`, which affects how fonts are rendered. When I login from LightDM theses settings work as I expect but when I login from a console and run X Windows with `startx` the font rendering is different. Which daemon do I need to add to `.xinitrc` to make the font renderer use my font settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need to put the font settings in `~/.Xdefaults` instead to make things work when I log in from the console.